# How can I remove a property from an entity in Drupal 7

Tags: entities, database

I have a custom entity that was create a long time ago.  Now we want to update the schema to remove a property (not a field) that was defined in the original schema.

I've reviewed the Drupal API for managing schema for custom entities and I don't see anything that allows me to remove the column during a hook_update_N function.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`db_drop_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_drop_field/7). Although it's called a "field" here, it's essentially the remove-a-column-from-the-DB-table function.

Example from `filter_update_7005()`:

```
// Drop the roles field from the {filter_format} table.
db_drop_field('filter_format', 'roles');
```

Comment: Just a note - the `hook_schema()` implementation will need to be updated too, to remove the same field, and there might be some other things to change depending on what modules are installed (e.g. if that property is used in a View, if there are `hook_entity_property_info()` implementations referring to it, other code, etc). Adding `drupal_flush_all_caches()` at the end of the update function would be a good idea too

Comment: @Clive I thought the caches will always be flushed after updates are finished. Is it really necessary to call `drupal_flush_all_caches()` manually?

Comment: I've just checked it up, and yes, after updates are finished, drupal flushes the caches: [`update_finished`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21update.inc/function/update_finished/7)

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. Yep you're right, withdrawn ;)